# Efficient XML Parsing

Tags: c#, xml

I'm working with the XMLSOCCER API which produces an XML response with the data.

They have a .NET library to work with their data.

```
var x = Client.GetAllLeagues(ApiKey);
XmlNodeList list = x.ChildNodes;
```

`GetAllLeagues(string ApiKey)` returns an XMLNode which is the root of the response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<XMLSOCCER.COM>
   <League>
      <Id>1</Id>
      <Name>English Premier League</Name>
      <Country>England</Country>
      <Historical_Data>Yes</Historical_Data>
      <Fixtures>Yes</Fixtures>
      <Livescore>Yes</Livescore>
      <NumberOfMatches>5640</NumberOfMatches>
      <LatestMatch>2015-04-13T21:00:00+00:00</LatestMatch>
   </League>
   <League>
      <Id>2</Id>
      <Name>English League Championship</Name>
      <Country>England</Country>
      <Historical_Data>Yes</Historical_Data>
      <Fixtures>Yes</Fixtures>
      <Livescore>Yes</Livescore>
      <NumberOfMatches>8335</NumberOfMatches>
      <LatestMatch>2015-04-17T20:45:00+00:00</LatestMatch>
   </League>
</XMLSOCCER.COM>
```

I can get to the Nodes and their values with the following:

```
for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++ )
            {
                var children = list.Item(i).ChildNodes;

                for(var j=0; j < children.Count; j++ ){

                  Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Key:{0} Value:{1}", children.Item(j).Name, children.Item(j).InnerText));

                }
            }
```

The problem I'm facing is that this feels largely inefficient. 
If I could use `XmlReader` it might make it easier to work with. But since `XmlReader.Create();` Expects a Stream, I can't work with the XmlNode that the API returns.

I thought I could use the example from the following: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056(v=vs.95).aspx

How would you parse the data?

Comment: Stop using their .NET library and call the API yourself. Create an `XDocument` from the XML string that comes back from the API call.

Comment: Wait... if their API retuns an `XmlNode` it means the XML is already parsed... Why would you want to stuff it back into a `XmlReader` to parse it a second time?

Comment: "I like `XmlReader` over `XDocument`/`XmlDocument`" type of question  feels completely personal preference. I'm not sure what input you expect from SO to help you decide what you like more (as there seem to be no particular reason to pick one over another based on information you've provided).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As CoderDennis suggested, I parse the request myself.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string API_KEY = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";


            XmlDocument xdoc = MakeRequest("http://www.xmlsoccer.com/FootballDataDemo.asmx/GetAllLeagues", API_KEY);

            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();


            // Create an XmlReader
            using (XmlReader reader = new XmlNodeReader(xdoc))
            {
                reader.ReadToFollowing("Id");
                Console.WriteLine(reader.Name +" " + reader.ReadElementContentAsString());
            }
            Console.ReadKey();

        }

        public static XmlDocument MakeRequest(string requestUrl, string API_KEY)
        {
            try
            {

                requestUrl = requestUrl + "?ApiKey=" + API_KEY;

                HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
                HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

                XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDoc.Load(response.GetResponseStream());
                return (xmlDoc);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);

                Console.Read();
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Lucas is also right, I can just parse it myself. I had a dumb moment. Thanks guys.